# Checking for duplicates in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an If and a nested-If that rejects rows with columns that have a value greater than 0. The nested-If is supposed to check for doubles and add up the duplicate values I need but it's not. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
 Dim rowValue As String
    Dim cellValue As String()

    If System.IO.File.Exists("shortlist.csv") Then

        Using streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New StreamReader("shortlist.csv")
            'Defines columns
            rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine()
            cellValue = rowValue.Split(",")
            With dgv.Columns
                .Add(cellValue(0).ToString, cellValue(0).ToString)
                .Add(cellValue(3).ToString, cellValue(3).ToString)
                .Add(cellValue(5).ToString, cellValue(5).ToString)
                .Add(cellValue(6).ToString, cellValue(6).ToString)
                .Add(cellValue(8).ToString, cellValue(8).ToString)
            End With

            ' Reading content
            While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
                Dim cnt As Integer = 0
                rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine()
                cellValue = rowValue.Split(",")
                If (cellValue(6) > 0) Then
                    'comparing works. need to tinnker with loop.
                    If (cellValue(0).ToString <> dgv.Rows(cnt).Cells("Phone Number").Value) Then
                        dgv.Rows.Add(cellValue(0).ToString, cellValue(3).ToString, cellValue(5).ToString, cellValue(6).ToString, cellValue(8).ToString)
                    Else
                        dgv.Rows(cnt).Cells(3).Value = (cellValue(6) + Integer.Parse(dgv.Rows(cnt).Cells(3).Value))
                        dgv.Rows(cnt).Cells(4).Value = (cellValue(8) + Integer.Parse(dgv.Rows(cnt).Cells(4).Value))
                        cnt += 1
                    End If

                End If
            End While
        End Using
    Else
        MsgBox("No File is Selected")
    End If
```

The .CSV file I'm working with has several columns, the first being a phone number. As I read every rows phone number and I come across a duplicate phone number I want to add the values from two columns to their unique rows.

Comment: Could you please give more of your code (where does cellValue() code from?) and explain a little more clearly what you are trying to achieve? Also, you don't explain what is expected from your code or what is actually happening instead.

Comment: cellValue() is a string array that has the current row from a .CSV file I'm trying to sort.

Comment: Have you considered that `.Cells("Phone Number").Value` will return an `object`? So in order to compare it with `ToString` value you should prefer `.Cells("Phone Number").Value.ToString()`.